# Apt-get not installing dependencies

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management

When I run:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

I get the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.35.0-1ubuntu2) but 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.8 is to be installed
                        Depends: libkrb5-dev but it is not going to be installed
                        Depends: librtmp-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

If I then try and install each of those dependencies manually, it gives me a similar error for another dependence of the dependency...dependency hell, which I thought apt-get was created to avoid.

Why isn't it installing the dependencies automatically?

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: It's installing dependencies automatically. I want you to put every dependency errors following libcurl3 in the question. We can then see who's creating problem

Answer (score 0):

When I run `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev` I get the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libcurl3
Suggested packages:
  libcurl4-doc libcurl3-dbg libidn11-dev libkrb5-dev libldap2-dev librtmp-dev
  libssh2-1-dev libssl-dev pkg-config zlib1g-dev
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 libcurl3 libcurl4-openssl-dev
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 639 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,745 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

I suspect your "broken packages" may be your problem. I would run `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get install -f` to see if you have anything held up. then run  your install again.

Comment: It's clear that broken package is the culprit here. This should be a comment instead as this is not answering the question